# Sorting coordinates to create a polygon gives messy results

Tags: r, gis

How can I obtain a polygon with the shape of South Africa starting with a set of coordinates representing the country boundaries organised in a data.frame? I am getting pretty close, but **I am not managing to create the polygon with the correct country shape.**

I am trying to plot an altitude map of South Africa similar to:

[image]

But with the altitude information outside the country boundaries masked out. Here is the code I have been using:

```
# Load relevant packages:
library(elevatr)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(sp)
library(fasterize)
library(maps)
library(mapdata)

SA_sf <- map("worldHires", "South Africa")
str(SA_sf); head(SA_sf)
map(SA_sf) # OK
# Extract coordinates
SA_coords <- data.frame(x=SA_sf$x, y=SA_sf$y)
plot(SA_coords, type="l") # just as it should be
```

Here I am simply subsetting to keep only continuous stretches of land and Lesotho:

```
SAml <- subset(SA_coords, x>16 & x<35 & y > -40 & y < -20)
plot(SAml, type="l")
```

The outline is messed up:

[image]

**The following should sort the problem out** by sorting the coordinates in a clock-wise order (`sort_points` also omits NAs)...

```
# library(devtools)
# install_github("skgrange/gissr")
library(gissr)
SAml <- sort_points(SAml, y = "y", x = "x", clockwise = T)
plot(SAml, type="l")
```

**...Instead the outline is still messed up, just in a different way!**
[image]

**What is wrong?**

For completeness, here is the rest of the code that I am using to mask out altitude data outside the country boundaries:

```
# Create a SpatialPoints object
prj_dd <- "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
examp_sp <- SpatialPoints(SAml, proj4string = CRS(prj_dd))

# get raster file of altitude:
sp_elev_epqs <- get_elev_raster(examp_sp, z=9)
# this takes a while to download, so once it's done it makes sense to save it on your computer:
# writeRaster(sp_elev_epqs, filename="~/Desktop/SA_mainland.grd")

# first, close your polygon 
# (first and last points must be identical)
SAml <- rbind(SAml, SAml[1,])
# Use various functions from the sf package to do the magic:
poly <- st_sf(st_sfc(st_polygon(list(as.matrix(SAml)))), crs = 4326)
str(poly)
# library(fasterize)
poly$POLYID <- 1:nrow(poly)
elevation_data <- sp_elev_epqs
polymap <- fasterize(poly, elevation_data, field = "POLYID")
## mask out elevation where there's no polygon
elevation_data[is.na(values(polymap))] <- NA
# or use:
# elevation_data <- mask(x=sp_elev_epqs, mask= poly)
plot(elevation_data, col = gray.colors(80, start = 0.9, end = 0.1, gamma = 2.2, alpha = NULL))
lines(SA_coords)
```

If I use a polygon based on `SAml` without reordering it with function `sort_points` I obtain:
[image]

If I use a polygon based on `SAml` after reordering it with function `sort_points` I obtain:
[image]

Comment: Can't you just use `raster::mask` ?

Comment: @RobertHijmans raster::mask can surely be used instead of elevation_data[is.na(values(polymap))] <- NA but does not solve the problem. It still relies on a masking polygon that is created with a wrong shape earlier on in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first create a SpatialPolygons object

```
library(raster)
library(mapdata)
require(maptools)

x <- map("worldHires", "South Africa", fill=TRUE)
y <- map2SpatialPolygons(x, IDs=1:length(x$names), proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
```

In this case you can simply retain the largest polygon

```
a <- area(y)
b <- y[which.max(a)]
plot(b)
```

If you want a data.frame

```
g <- geom(b)
```

A much simpler, alternative, approach would be

```
library(raster)
sa <- getData("GADM", country="South Africa", level=0)
```

Comment: Thanks! You've just allowed me to replace some 30 lines of wobbly code with two lines that actually work. I'm inexperienced with using R as a GIS and this thing was driving me bananas.